# Get Array of Nested JSON Struct in GO

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct

I am new to GoLang, and have a question about filling an array from nested JSON data. I have looked through Stack overflow yesterday and cannot find this exact topic, only threads that are similar, but do not provide a direct solution.

Lets say I have some nested JSON data like what is given below:

How can I create a nested struct to fill an array of the close prices. My code is given below.
My goal is to have an array where, arr = {157.92, 142.19, 148.26}

Thanks in advance! I greatly appreciate any help!

```
{
  "history": {
    "day": [
      {
        "date": "2019-01-02",
        "open": 154.89,
        "high": 158.85,
        "low": 154.23,
        "close": 157.92,
        "volume": 37039737
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-01-03",
        "open": 143.98,
        "high": 145.72,
        "low": 142.0,
        "close": 142.19,
        "volume": 91312195
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-01-04",
        "open": 144.53,
        "high": 148.5499,
        "low": 143.8,
        "close": 148.26,
        "volume": 58607070
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// DATA STRUCTURE
type Hist struct {
    History string `json:"history"`
}

type Date struct {
    Day string `json:"day"`
}

type Price struct {
    Close []string `json:"close"`
}

// HISTORICAL QUOTES
func get_quotes(arg1 string, arg2 string, arg3 string, arg4 string) []string {

    // arg1 = ticker symbol, arg2 = start, arg3 = end, arg4 = access token

    // TRADIER API
    apiUrl := "https://sandbox.tradier.com/v1/markets/history?symbol=" + arg1 + "&interval=daily&start=" + arg2 + "&end=" + arg3

    u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(apiUrl)
    urlStr := u.String()

    client := &http.Client{}
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", urlStr, nil)
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+arg4)
    r.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")

    resp, _ := client.Do(r)
    responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Println(string(responseData))

    var response Price
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&response)

    fmt.Println(response.Close)

    return response.Close

}
```

Comment: "I have looked through Stack overflow yesterday and cannot find this exact topic, only threads that are similar, but do not provide a direct solution." Have you tried implementing your own solution? Can you show that code? SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: The "day" field of your JSON does not contain a JSON object (in which the decode could match the key "close"); instead, it contains a list. You basically have two options here: 1) unmarshal the value of "day" to a slice of `struct` types each containing a single field of type `string` tagged `json:"close"`, and then post-process the result: walk the resulting slice and extract the values from the slice's elements; 2) Use the "streaming" facility of the JSON decoder to walk the list value and produce the resulting slice on the go. I strongly recommend to stick to the 1st approach for now.

Comment: [The language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang)—for basically the same reason you do not say PytongLang, JavaScriptLang etc.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I have tried implementing my own solution, its attached above.

Comment: @kostix Can you provide an example, I am not quite sure I understand

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should give you what you need. Your data structure does not correctly reflect the response from the API. I used [this tool](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to quickly convert the JSON value into a Go struct type. Once you're decoding the response correctly, then it's just a matter of iterating over each `Day` struct and appending the `close` value to an output array.

I added the core stuff for decoding and mapping the values. You can handle customizing the client, request, and headers however you'd like by combining what you've already got.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Response struct {
    History History `json:"history"`
}
type Day struct {
    Date   string  `json:"date"`
    Open   float64 `json:"open"`
    High   float64 `json:"high"`
    Low    float64 `json:"low"`
    Close  float64 `json:"close"`
    Volume int     `json:"volume"`
}
type History struct {
    Day []Day `json:"day"`
}

func main() {
    prices, err := closePrices()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(prices)
}

func closePrices() (out []float64, err error) {
    resp, err := http.Get("...")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    r := Response{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&r)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, d := range r.History.Day {
        out = append(out, d.Close)
    }
    return
}
```